# Applying opacity to multiple DIV classes

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am working on 'OnClick' functionality in jQuery. When we click parent Div property, only parent div and its child divs should be displayed other divs should fade out.

Please find the code below. HTML:

```
<div>1</div>
<div class="ree">2</div>
<div class="foo">items
  <div class = "bar">Shoes
     <div class="nike">3</div>
     <div class="puma">5</div>
     <div class="gap">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>4</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.foo').on('click',function ()
              {
$('div:not(.foo)').css('opacity','0.2')

              });
```

Here When I click on Div Class 'foo', Except 'foo' and its child divs like bar,nike,puma,gap div classes should be displayed and all other Div classes should fade out.

Please find the demo below,

http://jsfiddle.net/6V8hr/15/

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
$('.foo').on('click', function () {
    $(this).siblings('div').css('opacity','0.2');
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9nsYq/)

Answer (score 2):

Your `:not` selector just needs to exclude the child divs too. You can put multiple things in a not selector just like any other:

```
$('.foo').on('click', function(){
  $('div:not(.foo, .foo div)').css('opacity','0.2');
});
```

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6V8hr/17/

Answer (score 1):

You did not place any value in foo class div:

```
<div>1</div>
<div class="ree">2</div>
<div class="foo"> Value here              <-----
  <div class = "bar">Shoes
     <div class="nike">3</div>
<div class="puma">5</div>
<div class="gap">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>4</div>
```

Now, if you click 'Value here'. All the divs fade out. This is to make your code take affect.

---

To achieve what you desire in the question you need to use better a class matching qualifier. Use .sublings() or .children() as others mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to fade out all of the divs except for `.foo` and its children. Use the `$.siblings()` selector.

```
$('.foo').on('click', function () {
    $(this).siblings().css('opacity','0.2')
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/siblings/
- http://jsfiddle.net/6V8hr/16/